# Python - difficulty calling methods of parent (ElementTree) class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, parent-child, elementtree

Here is how I am importing ElementTree:

```
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

Here is a snippet of my class:

```
class Foo(ET.ElementTree):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if args[0] == "file":
            # populate from xml file
            self = load_xml(self, *args[1:])
        elif args[0] == "user_input":
            # populate from user_input
            self = load_from_user_input(self, *args[1:])
        else:
            raise ValueError("Error initializing Foo: Invalid argument")

    def save_xml(self, file_name):
        self.write(file_name + FOO_EXTENSION, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8', method='xml')
```

*init* and save_xml work as expected. Where things get confusing is any time I need to use the root of the Foo object in a method, such as to append something to the root of the Foo ElementTree:

```
root = self.getroot()
root.append(something)
```

This produces this error:

```
AttributeError: getroot
```

- How do I properly call getroot() from within Foo?
- Why doesn't self.getroot() work, but self.write() does?
- Is there something wrong with how I inherited from the ElementTree
  object?
- Am I obliviously running face-first into an important object-oriented
  conceptual hurdle?

Comment: `self=X` tends to be not good form ...

Comment: @Joran Beasley - as you can probably tell, I'm quite new to Python so I appreciate the critique. Could you expand on it a bit? Why is it bad form and what is the preferred alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not familliar with the ET.ElementTree Class but it basically goes something like this

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
       print "Base Constructor Recieved:",args,kwargs
       pass #do something with the args and kwargs

    def do_something(self,*args):
       print "CALLED BASE DO SOMETHING!"

class InheritsFromBase(Base):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        #modify args and kwargs how you want
        new_args = ["a","b","v"]
        super(Base,self).__init__(*new_args,**kwargs) #initialize super class

    def do_something(self,operator,lhs,rhs):
        print "Do Something InheritsFromBase %s%s%s"%(lhs,operator,rhs)
        super(Base,self).do_something("arg1","arg2","arg3","...")

x = InheritsFromBase()
x.do_something("%",5,4)
```

If a base class does not inherit from object, you may not be able to use the super statement an alternative is presented below (just the init method)

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    #modify args and kwargs how you want
    new_args = ["a","b","v"]
    Base.__init__(self,*new_args,**kwargs) #initialize super class
```

I suspect somewhere in here is what you are missing.  you probably need to call the super constructor somehow.

Comment: Thank you! So if I understand correctly, what I failed to do is initialize the base class along with the child class. If the base class inherits from object (I believe people refer to these as "new-style" classes), I can do this with super, otherwise I must do it the second way. 

Even if that's not exactly right, I at least know what I don't know and can research this on my own, so thanks again.